# I cant display the output from properties file in java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to read from a properties file and displaying the output in a text field but it just gives me a blank page. I know the codes isn't the best but I don't know another way.

```
Double income = Double.parseDouble(totalField.getText());

Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream("intput.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    if (income <= 11000) {
        taxMessage.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("tax"))));
        montaxMessage.setText("mon tax:" + String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("tax")) / 12));
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you any exception in the output (console/logs) ?

Comment: yes i do have. i couldnt post the whole code.

Comment: posting the exception code would be very helpful :)

Comment: its posted. the last line in the code.

Comment: is there is anyway i can post the whole code so that i would make more sense?

Comment: you can just copy and paste the whole code highlight it all and press the code button along with the error message that you are getting

Comment: @Ram just declare it as code block on editor and if you post exception or error log with it we can solve it faster.

Comment: I'm so slow :) @Aaron

Comment: @Ram can you show in your code where the variables totalField, taxMessage, and montaxMessage are defined then I would be able to diagnose your problem

Comment: @Ram you can paste the whole code by clicking Ctrl+A inside your java class, then copy paste it here

Answer (score 0):

*Your code looks fine. **Maybe your file is empty?***

Can you try if that code is printing your file?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("input.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("tax"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

***Empty?*** You can add data the code below:

```
output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

// set the properties value
prop.setProperty("database", "localhost");
prop.setProperty("dbuser", "mkyong");
prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

// save properties to project root folder
prop.store(output, null);
```

Also I think you can skip one step and use:

```
taxMessage.setText(prop.getProperty("tax"));
```

Comment: no the file is not empty the issu is with taxMessage.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("tax"))));   because i want to print it out in  a text filed not using system print out

Comment: What is the Class of the object taxMessage? Where do you declare it?

Comment: public class TAX extends Application  {
     @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        
        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Tax Calculator");
        sceneTitle.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.NORMAL,20));
        pane.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        Label total = new Label("Income:");
        pane.add(total, 0, 1);
        final TextField totalField = new TextField();
       pane.add(totalField, 1, 1);

Comment: and you want to set the text inside. So you have to work on creating a method in TAX called setText(String str), which will be taking the TextField and set the text inside it